# Objects in Array not showing in ng-repeat - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm quite new to AngularJS and I'm facing some problems showing objects from an array in my view.

I have the following javascript code:

```
// list initialization:
vm.latestInvoices = { invoices: []};
....

// adding function to viewmodel:
vm.getLatestInvoices = getLatestInvoices;
...

    function getLatestInvoices() {
        console.log("Test 1234");
        var servicename = "GetLatestInvoicesRequest";

        var params = {};

        httpCall(servicename, params).then(function (data) {
            vm.latestInvoices = data;
            console.log(data);
            return vm.latestInvoices;
        })["catch"](function (data) {
            console.log("getLatestInvoices error");
        });
    }
```

My HTML view:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
        <p id="overview-headline">Invoices Overview</p>
        <div class="scrollCustomers" ng-init="vm.getLatestInvoices()">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Client</th>
                        <th>Project</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Inv. Date</th>
                        <th>Start Date</th>
                        <th>End Date</th>
                        <th>DKK ex VAT</th>
                        <th>CIG</th>
                        <th>Attention</th>
                        <th>Cust. Manager</th>
                        <th>Regarding</th>
                        <th>Due Date</th>
                        <th>Finalized</th>
                        <th>Paid</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="invoice in invoices">
                        <td>{{invoice.CompanyName}}</td>
                        <td>Project Name</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>Default</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>N/A</td>
                        <td>N/A</td>
                        <td>N/A</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the Google Dev console, the array and it's objects are returned fine. The view doesnt return the default values, Project Name, Default and N/A, so my guess is that for some reason, invoices in ng-repeat is never called?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you define `httpCall`? Is it a **chain** from an `$http` promise where you did `.then (function(response){return response.data})`?

Comment: httpCall is a function declared in the same controller. It returns my JSON and works fine! :)

Comment: How did you invoke your controller? Did you use controllerAs syntax? Or did you do it vanilla?

Comment: function OverviewCtrl(..........)
var vm = this;

Comment: And your did you use `ng-controller="OverviewCtrl as vm"`?

Comment: You should probably change your code to `ng-repeat="invoice in vm.latestInvoices"` since you use `ng-init="vm.getLatestInvoices()"`

Comment: No, the index controller inherits the OverviewCtrl. I tried to use the solution you suggested, but unfortunately, no data is display in the list besides Project Name, Default and N/A, which is only returned once. The array has a length of 9 elements.

Comment: Did my solution solve your problem? If yes, then please accept my answer.

Comment: I discovered it was a minor error in my backend. My Response method which is sending the data back, was named LatestInvoices. All I had to do, was adding that to my ng-repeat.

vm.latestInvoices.LatestInvoices :) Anyway, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Attach the result to the `$scope`:

```
httpCall(servicename, params).then(function (data) {
        vm.latestInvoices = data;
        console.log(data);
        $scope.invoices = data;
    })["catch"](function (data) {
        console.log("getLatestInvoices error");
    });
}
```

Comment: like ?  

function getLatestInvoices() {
            console.log("Test 1234");
            var servicename = "GetLatestInvoicesRequest";

            var params = {};

            httpCall(servicename, params).then(function (data, $scope) {
                vm.latestInvoices = data;
                console.log(data);
                $scope.invoices = data;
            })["catch"](function (data) {
                console.log("getLatestInvoices error");
            });
        }

Comment: You don't need to inject `$scope` in your function.